# Как в CENTOS добавить пользователя в группу www-data?

Tags: linux, centos, веб-сервер

У меня стоит на VDS CMS Joomla и когда я через нее что-то ставлю то владельцем становится `apache`. В итоге, когда я пробую что то изменить по ftp мне это не удается. Я вынужден заходить через панель ISP и там менять права.

Я вычитал что нужно добавить моего пользователя в группу www-data, но как это сделать я не знаю, а в гугле информации по этому поводу пока еще не нашел.

Имя моего пользователя `testuser`.

А вот путь к папке с моим сайтом `/var/www/testuser/data/www/mysite.ru`

Операционная система у меня Centos, доступ по ssh тоже есть.

По ssh я хотел сделать так:

Добавить моего пользователя в группу этой командой:

```
sudo adduser testuser www-data
```

После:

```
chown testuser:www-data -R /var/www/testuser/data/www/mysite.ru
```

И на последок:

```
chmod -R 775 /var/www/testuser/data/www/mysite.ru
```

Но все это мне не удалось сделать из за неправильных команд.

Подскажите, что я не так делаю? Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 2):

> Добавить моего пользователя в группу этой командой
>
> ```
> sudo adduser testuser www-data
> ```

в *redhat-основном* дистрибутиве такой синтаксис не «пройдёт». потому что `/usr/sbin/adduser` — это всего лишь символическая ссылка на `/usr/sbin/useradd`, а программа *useradd* не предназначена для **добавления** пользователя в группу.

такой синтаксис «пройдёт» в *debian-основных* дистрибутивах, где `/usr/sbin/adduser` — это *perl-скрипт*, про который в `man adduser` написано:

> **adduser** and **addgroup** are friendlier front ends to the low level tools like **useradd**, **groupadd** and **usermod** programs.

мой вольный перевод:

> **adduser** and **addgroup** — это обёртки вокруг низкоуровневых инструментов **useradd**, **groupadd** и **usermod**.

---

т.е., для добавления пользователя в группу вам придётся воспользоваться низкоуровневым инструментом `usermod`, который это как раз и умеет:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G группа пользователь
```

где:

- `-a` — добавить пользователя в дополнительную(-ые) группу(-ы). используется только вместе с опцией `-G`
- `-G группы` — список дополнительных групп (если указано больше одной группы, то разделитель — запятая)

подробнее смотрите с помощью `man usermod` в вашей системе.

---

посмотреть текущее членство в группах можно, например, с помощью программы *groups*:

```
$ groups root
root : root bin daemon sys adm disk wheel
```

Answer (score 0):

Для добавления пользователя в группу вроде как используется не `useradd` (эта команда добавляет нового пользователя), а `usermod`:

```
sudo usermod -aG www-data testuser
```

Comment: А -aG это что ?

Comment: [man usermod](http://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod) это опции значат добавить пользователя в указанные группы, без удаления из других.

Comment: Это будут правильные команды?
`sudo usermod -aG www-data testuser`

`chown testuser:www-data -R /var/www/testuser/data/www/mysite.ru`

`chmod -R 775 /var/www/testuser/data/www/mysite.ru`

Comment: @Анатолий Ну похоже на то, но все таки лучше поясните, что вы имели ввиду под  `Но все это мне не удалось сделать, из за неправильных команд.` То есть консоль ругалась на что-либо или что?

Comment: Когда делал sudo adduser testuser www-data то появлялась таблица с подсказками.